# Java, list of objects, change values in a loop

Tags: java, list, loops, object

My program has 4 `Computer` objects with different values, from `Make`, `Model`, `Productnumber`, `Amount`, and `Shelfnumber`.
They are coming from a class `Computer` which extends from class `Product`. I add the objects to an object list, now I need to get the `Shelfnumber`s (the last value in the objects) from each object and add a different amount to them depending on what the values are.

The question I have is, is there any way to go through each of the objects in a loop. The current loop only does it for the first computer object, `t1`. Now I would need it to get the `Shelfnumber` for `t2`, `t3` and `t4` in the same loop.

I.e., get `t1`'s Shelfnumber -> check what the value is -> add to it -> get `t2`'s `Shelfnumber` and do the same.

```
public class Main {

    public void computers() {
        ArrayList<Object> computers = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Computer t1 = new Computer("Razer", "Blade 15", "65732", 3, 12); computers.add(t1);
        Computer t2 = new Computer("Apple", "MacBook Pro", "8732", 21, 15); computers.add(t2);
        Computer t3 = new Computer("Asus", "Aspire 5", "7532", 5, 2); computers.add(t3);
        Computer t4 = new Computer("Lenovo", "Legion 5", "3437", 2, 150); computers.add(t4);
        int shelfNumber = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < computers.size(); i++) {
            shelfNumber = t1.getShelfnumber();
            if (shelfNumber < 10) {
                shelfNumber = shelfNumber + 10;
            } else if (shelfNumber > 10 && shelfNumber < 100) {
                shelfNumber = shelfNumber + 30;
            } else {
                shelfNumber = shelfNumber + 500;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(shelfNumber);

        System.out.println(t1.toString());
        System.out.println(t2.toString());
        System.out.println(t3.toString());
        System.out.println(t4.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main ohj = new Main();
        ohj.computers();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating an `ArrayList<Object>` but why are you not adding items to it?

Comment: Is there a reason you declared your list as `ArrayList<Object>` instead of `ArrayList<Computer>`? Since it's a list that only seems to hold `Computer` objects not declaring that as the generic type will just make working with that List and its objects harder for you.

Comment: Am I not ? there computers.add(t1), computers.add(t2); but they are at the end of the object creation.

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed it in the corner :-)

Comment: @Aker It is quite unusual to have those 2 operations in the same line. Usually in code people expect a new line after `;`

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip, I thought it would look cleaner, but  I guess I'll change it for clarity, thanks!

Comment: Also note: why use named variables in the first place. Just do `computers.add( new Computer(...))` several times. Then you wouldnt have had that problem of using some t1 in the first place. And then: use `List<Computer> computers = new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the comment, I'll look into this approach too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to refer to the objects in the list, and not to `t1` directly:

```
for (Computer t : computers) {
    shelfNumber = t.getShelfnumber();
    if (shelfNumber < 10) {
        shelfNumber = shelfNumber + 10;
    } else if (shelfNumber > 10 && shelfNumber < 100) {
        shelfNumber = shelfNumber + 30;
    } else {
        shelfNumber = shelfNumber + 500;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
As noted in the comment, you should define `computers` as a `List<Computer>`, not a `List<Object>`.

Comment: That for loop won't work with a `List<Object>`.

Comment: Yes, I tried this but it gives me "Cannot resolve method 'getShelfnumber' in Object.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS good catch, didn't even notice that. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, Oh alright, I didn't know you could do it as a custom list if it's holding only one type of objects, what's the appropriate case to use the Objects list then? And thanks guys for your time, I got it working! :)